# How can I also get an element's index when I grep through an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

Let's say I have this list:

```
my @list = qw(one two three four five);
```

and I want to grab all the elements containing `o`. I'd have this:

```
my @containing_o = grep { /o/ } @list;
```

But what would I have to do to also receive an index, or to be able to access the index in `grep`'s body?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
my @index_containing_o = grep { $list[$_] =~ /o/ } 0..$#list;  # ==> (0,1,3)

my %hash_of_containing_o = map { $list[$_]=~/o/?($list[$_]=>$_):() } 0..$#list
            # ==> ( 'one' => 0, 'two' => 1, 'four' => 3 )
```

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils).  You can do lots of handy things with arrays without having to roll your own version, plus it's faster (because it's implemented in C/XS):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index indexes);

my $index_of_matching_element = first_index { /o/ } @list;
```

For all matching indices, and then their corresponding elements, you can do:

```
my @matching_indices = indexes { /o/ } @list;
my @matching_values = @list[@matching_indices];
```

or just:

```
my @matching_values = grep { /o/ } @list;
```

Comment: Won't this return just the index of the first element?

Comment: Yep. I think Ether meant to use the `indexes` function which will give a list of all indexes that return true for the block.

Comment: Yes I did... I hit submit too soon before checking my work. thanks :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fact that it's C/XS implementation makes it faster

Answer (score 2):

This populates 2 arrays with what you want, looping through the input array once:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @list = qw(one two three four five);
my @containing_o;
my @indexes_o;
for (0 .. $#list) {
    if ($list[$_] =~ /o/) {
        push @containing_o, $list[$_];
        push @indexes_o   , $_;
    }
}
```